# Is these usage habits leading my MacBooks result to battery bulge?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a Macbook Air and two Macbook Pros. All of their batteries got a bulge.

I like to use them in this way:

1. Always plugged to the power if there is one. 95% of the time, I plugged it to power. I do this because I think when power is on, the software runs fast.
2. Never restart the OS. I do this because I think it saves me a lot of time waiting for the system to restart (even though it doesn't take much)
3. Never shut down the machine, if I need to take the device, I just fold the screen (if not connecting to an external display)
4. 70% of the time, I use an external display and fold the screen when using it. I do this because I like to put my keyboard on the top of the MacBook, so this would save a lot of space.

I hope to get some advice that which one (or more) of the above habits are causing the battery bulge.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272113 about leaving your Mac connected all the time. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36338 about an external monitor.

Comment: See Apple's authoritative advice on getting the most from your batteries – https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/